# How data.table sorts strings when setting key

Tags: r, data.table

Yesterday I had to spend some time trying to find a bug in my code and I found that `data.table` package sorts strings in a way a bit different from base. Is this a normal behavior and what is the most efficient way (which has benefits of `data.table`) to reproduce results obtained with base `order` function? Here is a toy reproducible example:

```
library(data.table)
options(stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

d <- data.frame(cn=c("USA","Ubuntu","Uzbekistan"))
d[order(d$cn),,drop=F]

#          cn
#2     Ubuntu
#1        USA
#3 Uzbekistan

dt <- data.table(d)
setkey(dt, cn)
dt

#           cn
#1:        USA
#2:     Ubuntu
#3: Uzbekistan

options(stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors())
```

OS Windows 7

Comment: This was an old question referring to data.table versions around 1.8.x (2013)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Update March 2014**

There's been some debate about this one. As of v1.9.2 we've settled for now on `setkey` sorting using C locale; e.g., all capital letters come before all lower case letters, regardless of user's locale. This was a change made in v1.8.8 which we had intended to reverse but have stuck with for now.

Consider `save()`-ing a keyed table in your locale and a colleague `load()`-ing it in a different locale. When they join to that table it may no longer work correctly if it were locale sort order. We have to think a bit more carefully if `setkey` is to allow locale ordering again, probably by saving the locale name along with the "sorted" attribute, so `data.table` can at least compare and detect if the current locale is different to the one that ran `setkey`.

It's also for speed reasons as sorting according to locale is much slower than C locale. Although, we can do it as efficiently as possible and allowing it optionally would be ideal.

Hence, this is now a feature request and further comments are very welcome.

[FR#4842 setkey to sort using session's locale not C locale](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?group_id=240&atid=978&func=detail&aid=4842)

---

---

Nice catch! The call to `setkey` in turn calls `setkeyv` and that calls `fastorder` to "order" the columns/entries that in turn calls `chorder`.

`chorder` in turn calls a C function `Ccountingcharacter.c`. Now, here I suppose the problem comes due to "locale".

Let's see what "locale" I'm on my mac.

```
Sys.getLocale()
# [1] "en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8"
```

Now let's see how `order` sorts it:

```
x <- c("USA", "Ubuntu", "Uzbekistan")
order(x)
# [1] 2 1 3
```

Now, let's change the "locale" to "C".

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL", "C")
# [1] "C/C/C/C/C/en_US.UTF-8"

order(x)
# [1] 1 2 3
```

From `?order`:

> The sort order for character vectors will depend on the collating sequence of the locale in use: see `Comparison`.

From `?Comparison`:

> Comparison of strings in character vectors is lexicographic within the strings using the collating sequence of the locale in use: see locales. The collating sequence of locales such as en_US is normally different from C (which should use ASCII) and can be surprising. Beware of making any assumptions about the collation order: e.g. in Estonian Z comes between S and T, and collation is not necessarily character-by-character – in Danish aa sorts as a single letter, after z....

So, basically, `order` as well under "C" locale, gives the same order as `data.table`'s `setkey`. My guess is that the C-function called by `chorder` automatically runs on C-locale which will compare ascii values for which "S" comes before "b".

It's probably important to bring this to @MatthewDowle's attention (if he's not already aware of it). So, I'd suggest that you file this as a bug [here](https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/?atid=975&group_id=240&func=browse) (just to be sure).

Comment: nice job, but I wouldn't call this a bug, maybe a feature request

Answer (score 2):

Well, I am not sure what the most efficient way is but you can do the following to reproduce the data.frame result.

```
dt[order(dt$cn)]

           cn
1:     Ubuntu
2:        USA
3: Uzbekistan
```

Comment: this works fine, but with bigger data set it might be much slower than setkey

Comment: I agree. It seems like it might have something to do with the sort method used in setkey. This is what it says in the ?setkey (however I couldn't find an option to set the sort method in setkey)

_The sort is attempted with the very fast "radix" method in sort.list. If that fails, the sort reverts to the default method in order. That logic is repeated column by column._

Maybe someone else knows more?