# How does data.table::setkey sort characters in R?

Tags: r, string, sorting, data.table, character

I have found in data.table package `setkey` function doesn't sort character values like `base::sort` function. What's the logic behind character sorting in `setkey`, and how can I make `setkey` and `sort` consistent with each other?

```
temp_dt <- data.table(index = c(letters[1:5], LETTERS[1:5]))
print(temp_dt$index)
# [1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "A" "B" "C" "D" "E"

setkey(temp_dt, index)
print(temp_dt$index)
# [1] "A" "B" "C" "D" "E" "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"

sort(temp_dt$index)
# [1] "a" "A" "b" "B" "c" "C" "d" "D" "e" "E"
# different from `setkey` results.
```

Comment: Maybe related to the issue [setkey to sort using session's locale not C locale](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/565)

Comment: Also this SO post: [How data.table sorts strings when setting key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18336304/how-data-table-sorts-strings-when-setting-key).